# Slim controller issue : must be an instance of ContainerInterface, instance of Slim\\Container given

Tags: php, model-view-controller, slim

I am trying to use controller in Slim however keep getting the error

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
TopPageController::__construct() must be an instance of ContainerInterface,
instance of Slim\Container given

My index.php

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require 'settings.php';

spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    require ("../classes/" . $classname . ".php");
});

$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Welcome");
    return $response;
});
$app->get('/method1', '\TopPageController:method1');
$app->run();
?>
```

My TopPageController.php

```
<?php
class TopPageController {
   protected $ci;
   //Constructor
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ci) {
       $this->ci = $ci;
   }

   public function method1($request, $response, $args) {
        //your code
        //to access items in the container... $this->ci->get('');
        $response->getBody()->write("Welcome1");
        return $response;
   }

   public function method2($request, $response, $args) {
        //your code
        //to access items in the container... $this->ci->get('');
        $response->getBody()->write("Welcome2");
        return $response;
   }

   public function method3($request, $response, $args) {
        //your code
        //to access items in the container... $this->ci->get('');
        $response->getBody()->write("Welcome3");
        return $response;
   }
}
?>
```

Thanks. I am using Slim 3.

Comment: You do not have the proper namespace on your ContainerInterface.  It should be `Interop\Container\ContainerIterface`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code seems to be based on the Slim 3 documentation at http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html which does not contain all the required code to avoid the Exception being thrown.

You basically have two options to make it work.

**Option 1:**

Import the namespace in your `index.php`, just like it is being done for `Request` and `Response`:

```
use \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface as ContainerInterface;
```

**Option 2:**

Change the constructor of the TopPageController to:

```
public function __construct(Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $ci) {
    $this->ci = $ci;
}
```

---

**TL;DR**

The reason the Exception is thrown is that the `Slim\Container` class is using the `Interop\Container\ContainerInterface` interface (see the source code):

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
```

Since `Slim\Container` is extending `Pimple\Container`, the following should all be valid (working) type declarations for your controller's method:

```
public function __construct(Pimple\Container $ci) {
    $this->ci = $ci;
}
```

...or even...

```
public function __construct(ArrayAccess $ci) {
    $this->ci = $ci;
}
```

Comment: If this was the result of upgrading Slim, the answer from Trendfischer is best.  `Interop\Container` is deprecated and Slim changed to Psr\Container.  Better to update your code to match the update from Slim.

Answer (score 7):

Based on a later [change in Slim3](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/commit/305e2df322dbb69ecd3f57ff2732f0ba9596aac5) (from version 3.12.2 to 3.12.3) a slightly different ContainerInterface is required. This changes `\Interop\` to `\Psr\`. Add the following on top of you code or change the existing `use`:

```php
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
```

Or change the constructor:

```php
public function __construct(\Psr\Container\ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Comment: The problem occurred for me when updating from version 3.12.2 => 3.12.3

Comment: @DariuszChowański Thanks, I forgot to mention it. I believe they made this patch version when the Interop module got a "deprecated" status. I added the version info to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just paste the below code in your controller

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface as ContainerInterface;
```

Your controller's construct should look like the one below

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
    parent::__construct($container);
}
```

I think you are making mistake in giving namespace in controller for `ContainerInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Since [container-interop/container-interop](https://packagist.org/packages/container-interop/container-interop) is *deprecated*, simply replace it with [psr/container](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/container) (`Psr\Container\ContainerInterface`).